# Upload an image to Unity, but it change color, how do i fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twQRS.png)
The left one is the image I upload to Unity, I open it in Sprite Editor.
The right one is the image I draw in Aseprite.

Comment: Looks like something to do with your file export setttings from asperite?

Answer (score 0):

To use an image in unity it needs to be a sprite.

To create a sprite in Unity, we must supply the engine with a texture.

Get a standard image file such as a PNG or JPG that you want to use, save it, and then drag the image into the Assets region of Unity.

Next, drag the image from the Assets into the Scene Hierarchy. You will notice that as soon as you let go of the mouse button, a new GameObject with your texture’s name shows up in the list.

For a more concise explanation [visit this site and follow the steps](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unity/unity_creating_sprites.htm#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20sprite%20in,Assets%20into%20the%20Scene%20Hierarchy.)!

Comment: Never use JPEG for textures. PNG is great and TGA is an alternative. However, JPG comes with artifacts (that you don't want with pixel art) and no alpha channel, so it is essentially useless for Gamedev.

Answer (score 0):

Check the format in unity. I had the same problem and changing the format from automatic to RGBA 32 bit solved all the problems